# Heavily customized notifications on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, notifications

I am learning to develop mobile applications. I started with Android, but would like to make a simple test app that runs on both Android and iOS (maybe with Cordova which I've recently discovered, but that's another discussion).

I want to play with notifications, but I'm finding the official documentation a bit unclear, if someone could shed some light on the following doubts I would be very grateful..

1. Is it possible for an app to have persistent (can't be swiped away)  programmatically defined notifications on Android and IOS?
2. I know that on Android notifications can contain various controls such as buttons, can these be changed dynamically during the life of the notification? What about iOS? To what degree can a notification be customized and can it change dynamically or does it have to be destroyed and recreated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is possible to have a persistent notification on Android (usually used to display progress on an ongoing operation), which is documented fairly clearly in the [notifications documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Progress). On iOS, as far as I know, a persistent notification is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18944917/5115932).
2. Until recently notifications on iOS were static, but with [iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/whats-new/) notifications can now be defined with a [detail view upon 3D Touch](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/features/notifications/) that can be dynamic.