# Create a persistent iOS banner notification

Tags: ios, notifications

I don't know about early versions of IOS, but iOS 11 has a feature:

[image]

How to create a persistent notification programmatically with swift in my IOS app? I didn't found any docs about it.

I also found this answer: [Create a persistent notification in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944883/create-a-persistent-notification-in-ios) but it was a long time ago, maybe the situation has changed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature you're describing is a *local notification*. See the docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

You cannot *force* notifications or their style on the user. That is what the Settings window in your screen shot is about. Only the user can decide whether your notification alert will appear as Temporary or Persistent. (The user can also decide to suppress your notifications completely.)

Comment: Yes, I know about it. My app uses local notification. So, the situation has not changed from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944883/create-a-persistent-notification-in-ios

Comment: That's great; it wasn't clear from your question where the doubt was. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer -  I agree with you, because I didn't find anything in docs

Comment: I know it's only been two months since this question was asked... But is this still the case? Boss is getting pissed. Only other solution i can come up with is setting a flag or timer to re create the notification once again. But my question is if you use a "Custom Notification Interface" do you know if you can force notification response?

Comment: @DaWiseguy "do you know if you can force notification response" I don't really know what those words are supposed to mean. But since the user can turn off notifications for your app entirely, I don't see how you can suppose you can "force" anything.

Comment: @matt Guess I should say: "Can you make a notification REQUIRE a response from the user before it is deleted?" But I agree, it seems like the user simply has first option on whether or not to ignore a notification.

Comment: @matt if the banner style is persistent, the banner remains visible until the user interacts with it.