# Notification banner style iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I knew that there are a similar questions. Also I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812901/create-a-persistent-ios-banner-notification) one. Great answer, but I want to clarify two details.

1. Is there any way to check in code which kind of notification's banner style user use for your app "Temporary" or "Persistent"?
2. When iPhone is locked and user received notification from Reminders, then unlocked iPhone and locked it again, the notification will still appears on locked screen. If we do the same with another app that have "Persistent" banner style, the notification will not still appears when iPhone will locked again. So, how we can achieve notification banner behavior like in Apple's Reminders app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to check in code which kind of notification's banner style user use for your app "Temporary" or "Persistent"

Sure. Call UNUserNotificationCenter `getNotificationSettings`. The result is a UNNotificationSettings whose `alertStyle` is `.banner` [temporary] or `.alert` [persistent] (or `.none`, of course).

> When iPhone is locked and user received notification from Reminders, then unlocked iPhone and locked it again, the notification will still appears on locked screen. If we do the same with another app that have "Persistent" banner style, the notification will not still appears when iPhone will locked again.

I don't think the behavior in the lock screen has anything to do with the "Persistent" setting. I think that with any app for which lock screen notifications are permitted, if all you do is turn on the screen (from black to lock screen) and look at it and then turn the screen off again, if there was a notification visible it will be visible the next time you do that same thing.

Comment: Wow, Matt... Thank you for the answer! With the first question is pretty clear, thank you! With the second... I mean not the "turn on the screen (from black to lock screen)", but unlocked phone with biometricId and then locked it. The key point that notification from Reminders are alway still visible until user read it or close, at that time other notification after unlocked/locked iPhone moved to "Older Notification", even if they didn't read yet. Can it be the privilege behavior for Apple's engineers? Or can we achieve the same? Or it is uncontrollable?

Comment: Or if you know, would you be kind enough to tell me, if there some priorities for local or remote notifications, and for native Apple apps and others apps?

Comment: I think what you're looking at is an alarm (EKAlarm), not a local notification.

Comment: "Call UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationSettings", please provide an example.