# How to force notifications to stay on the lock screen?

Tags: ios

For example I got a message and it shows on the lock screen. I unlock the phone and lock it again. And the message goes from the lock screen to the notification centre. Can I prevent it? I want the message to stay on the lock screen constantly like in the Reminders app.

Can't find anything in docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649633-init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve has nothing to do with a notification, this functionality comes from **EventKit** framework. More on that you can read on this link: [Setting an Alarm](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/setting_an_alarm).

This was also explained by @matt on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697020/notification-banner-style-ios).